# Custom WooCoomerce product page, add to cart button redirecting to product's page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We've built a custom product page with 2 separate products and when ever someone hits the 'Add To Cart' button it redirects to the product's page. we want them to to stay on the custom page.

here's [the link](http://dev.incredible.ninja/2017-feast-tabernacles-step-2/) to the page in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a custom redirection when one of those products are added to the cart, or you can add a Ajax feature to your 'Add to Cart' button.

There's lots of plugins which does both, but better would be to do it on your functions.php file.

**Add to cart via Ajax**

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53280/woocommerce-add-a-product-to-cart-programmatically-via-js-or-php/53516#53516

**Custom Redirect:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_on_add_to_cart' );
function redirect_on_add_to_cart() {
        if ( isset( $_POST['add-to-cart'] ) ) {
            $product_id = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['add-to-cart'] );

            if($product_id == productid || $product_id == productid2){
                return get_permalink( page_id_to_redirect );
            }       
        }
}
```

Change productid and productid2 to your actual products ids... Also set the page_id_to_redirect to your custom page id.